# Accept Drop in an embedde form

Tags: delphi

I can setup a drag and drop simple example as outlined in the following code 
(excerpted from http://www.chami.com/tips/delphi/111196D.html)

But if I use an embedded form (a form contained in another form I am unable to drop a file on an embedded form: the embedded form does not act as a drop target

```
unit dropfile;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes,
  Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }

    //>>>

    // declare our DROPFILES message handler
    procedure AcceptFiles( var msg : TMessage );
      message WM_DROPFILES;
    //<<<
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  //>>>
  //
  // this unit contains certain
  // functions that we'll be using
  //
  ShellAPI;
  //<<<

{$R *.DFM}

//>>>
procedure TForm1.AcceptFiles( var msg : TMessage );
const
  cnMaxFileNameLen = 255;
var
  i,
  nCount     : integer;
  acFileName : array [0..cnMaxFileNameLen] of char;
begin
  // find out how many files we're accepting
  nCount := DragQueryFile( msg.WParam,
                           $FFFFFFFF,
                           acFileName,
                           cnMaxFileNameLen );

  // query Windows one at a time for the file name
  for i := 0 to nCount-1 do
  begin
    DragQueryFile( msg.WParam, i,
                   acFileName, cnMaxFileNameLen );

    // do your thing with the acFileName
    MessageBox( Handle, acFileName, '', MB_OK );
  end;

  // let Windows know that you're done
  DragFinish( msg.WParam );
end;
//<<<

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //>>>
  //
  // tell Windows that you're
  // accepting drag and drop files
  //
  DragAcceptFiles( Handle, True );
  //<<<
end;

end.
```

Comment: We're not going to go to some other site to figure out what you're asking. Please put all relevant content **here**, in your question itself. If the relevant content is somewhere else, and that off-site location is unavailable, your question has no value to this site or future readers.

Comment: @KenWhite I apologize: you are absolutely right: so I edited my question and now all the relevant content is here.

Comment: So is being embedded relevant or not?

Comment: Thanks. I've retracted my close vote. It would seem pretty clear to me from reading that code that it works because of the call to `DragQueryFiles` which passes the form's handle. Wouldn't it make sense that to do so from an embedded form, you would call it with that embedded form's handle?

Comment: Thank you @KenWhite again! you gave me an important lesson: *Always* show the code! And definitely this is at least as important as the answer that solves the problem

Comment: @SertacAkyuz yes, being embedded is relevant: on a normal (non embedded form) drag and drop works fine, only if I try to drop on and embedded form it does not work

Comment: @FabioVitale, No. the fact that the form is embedded makes no difference. A non-embedded form can also recreate it's handle after the form is created. Remy's answer applies in both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `DragAcceptFiles()` in the Form's `OnCreate` event. That event is called only one time during a Form's lifetime. But the Form's window may be recreated multiple times during the Form's lifetime. And that is certainly the case when embedding a Form inside another window.  The Form's window gets recreated, but you are not calling `DragAcceptFiles()` on the newly recreated Form window. That is why your `WM_DROPFILES` message handler stops working.

To account for window recreation, you need to override the Form's virtual `CreateWnd()` and call `DragAcceptFiles()` from there instead.

```
unit dropfile;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
    procedure DestroyWnd; override;
  public
    // declare our DROPFILES message handler
    procedure AcceptFiles(var msg: TMessage); message WM_DROPFILES;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  ShellAPI;

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TForm1.AcceptFiles(var msg: TMessage);
var
  i, nCount: Integer;
  acFileName: array [0..MAX_PATH-1] of Char;
begin
  // find out how many files we're accepting
  nCount := DragQueryFile(msg.WParam, $FFFFFFFF, nil, 0);
  // query Windows one at a time for the file name
  for i := 0 to nCount-1 do
  begin
    DragQueryFile(msg.WParam, i, acFileName, MAX_PATH);
    // do your thing with the acFileName
    MessageBox(Handle, acFileName, '', MB_OK);
  end;
  // let Windows know that you're done
  DragFinish(msg.WParam);
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  // tell Windows that you're
  // accepting drag and drop files
  DragAcceptFiles(Handle, True);
end;

procedure TForm1.DestroyWnd;
begin
  // tell Windows that you're no
  // longer accepting drag and drop files
  DragAcceptFiles(Handle, False);
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

Comment: And what if I want to change the drop target on the embedded form? Say I have a ListView on the embedded form and I want to drop files to it.

Comment: @FabioVitale you would have to subclass the ListView to intercept its window (re)creation to call `DragAcceptFiles()`. You can derive a new component, or use an interposer class. See [Two Approaches to Sub-classing Components Compared](http://caryjensen.blogspot.com/2014/01/two-approaches-to-sub-classing.html)

Comment: Thank you @remy I will  try to create a subclass of my listview (I will use the interceptor approach). Then, in the subclass, what virtual method should I override in order to call DragAcceptFiles()?

Comment: @FabioVitale override `CreateWnd()`, same as with the Form. It is a virtual method of `TWinControl`, so every windowed control has it.